# Доступ к глобальным переменным из подключаемого файла

Tags: php

прошу подсказать, как решить данную проблему!

Существует index.php:

```php
<?php
$CONFIG = require_once('config/config.php');
require_once $CONFIG->RES->CONTS.'/resources.controller.php';

controller('database');
...
```

resources.controller.php содержит

```php
function controller($name){
    $argc = func_num_args();
    $path = $CONFIG->RES->CONTS;
    if($argc > 1)
        for ($i=1; $i < $argc; $i++)
            $path.='/'.func_get_arg($i);
    require_once "$path/$name.controller.php";
}
```

При открытии index.php вылазит ошибка вида

```
Warning: require_once(/database.controller.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /.../controllers/resources.controller.php on line 79

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/database.controller.php' (include_path='.:') in /.../controllers/resources.controller.php on line 79
```

Ясно, что $CONFIG не доступен в подключаемом resources.controller.php, а мне как раз и надо его подключить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать!

Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Comment: а почему бы вам просто не подключить файл конфиг в сам контроллер?

Comment: `function controller($name, $CONFIG)` и передаёте туда конфиг

Comment: @AntonKucenko потому что контроллеров много путь к ним находится в файле конфиге, без него из контроллера и конфиг не подключить

Comment: @ArchDemon в resource.controller.php помимо этой ещё 24 функции, использующей $CONFIG

Comment: Всё остальное - порочные практики. Начните с шаблона синглтон. Но вообще для чётких пацанов придумали composer и psr-4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашёл кратчайший вариант решения

```php
global $CONFIG;
```

В начале подключаемых функций